# 10/3 uf cable for 30 amp circuit

Tags: voltage, electrical

I have a 10/3 UF cable running to my greenhouse, but I am not sure of the exact distance it runs underground.

I want to add an electric heater and would like to use a 30 amp circuit but my only concern is the distance of the cable.

The heater calls for a 30 amp circuit, but the manual states that it draws 20 amps.

Is there a way I can test the loss over the distance to inform me if the 10AWG cable is sufficient?

Comment: Can you estimate the distance?  It should be okay to around a 100 feet.  150 feet it starts to get iffy.  Can see this calculator to see about your distance.  http://wiresizecalculator.net/calculators/voltagedrop.htm.

Comment: Can you estimate the distance?  That would be easier than trying to measure the loss, or cable resistance.

Comment: What is the approximate distance ?  If you buy a 240V heater you should be good up to about 150ft -- double the distance and double the heat output vs a 120V one.

Answer (score 4):

The [wire salesman](https://www.southwire.com/calculator-vdrop) would certainly prefer you stay under 3% calculated voltage drop *on the actual load*. (NEVER compute voltage drop on breaker trip).  However this is purely optional in North America other than Canada, so "the person who pays the electric bill" is left to decide how much voltage drop they're willing to pay for.  Then they are free to crunch the numbers and consider buying larger wire *now* to save a little bit of money on power loss from the voltage drop.

Now, even in Canada, you will be under 3% drop if your 10/3 is under 180 feet, sorry, 55 metres.

Outside of Canada I wouldn't be overly concerned until the voltage drop is over 6%, so double that distance.

Oh. One other thing.  If you don't have an extremely favorable power tariff, you should not be using a "toaster" resistance electric heater.

I realize they're cheap to buy but figure out what you¡ll be paying for power. I see DIY mini-split heat pumps all the time for under $1000 and they *do* work in the icy cold.  They will be 4-6 times more efficient than resistive electric heat most of the time, and fall below 2.5x efficient only rarely.  [Our heat pump hero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI) figured that out for Chicago in a cold year, and only 100 hours that year did it fall below 2.5x efficiency.

Comment: Thank you for your experience and recommendation. Yes ultimately I do want to install a heat pump with a ng backup heater.  This is hopefully a temporary solution for just one season, but as priorities go it may be a bit longer.

Comment: @mbbom good idea.  For gas "emergency heat" I'm a super-fan of Empire/Williams style wall or floor furnaces *that do not require any electricity to operate*.  It's cool hearing ours go "Tha-woop woosh" when we adjust the thermostat, even though we're in the middle of a blackout!  There are ways to control them with a normal 24V thermostat without breaking their "works with power off" functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a back of the envelope estimation.

Assume the cable run to your greenhouse is 100 feet.  That would be 200 feet out and back, or hot and neutral.  #10 cable has a resistance of close to 1 ohm per 1,000 feet.

So 200 feet total gives us 0.2 ohms of resistance.  You might want to up that a bit for connections, etc.  So let's use 0.3 ohms.

20 A through 0.3 ohms gives a voltage drop of 6 V.  So if you start out with 115 V at your main panel, you may end up with 115 V - 6 V = 109 V at your heater.  You heater will be perfectly happy at this voltage.  If you have any electronics out in the greenhouse, they may start to complain.  You would have to look at the rating plate on the device to see what input voltage range it is specified to work at.

Comment: I think OP is worried about the heater drawing more amperage that that distance of wire is rated for. The appliance might be fine but is the power draw exceeding the rating of the wire? At that distance, should the breaker be a 25 or even a 20? Your wouldn't want to use a 20 amp breaker at capacity for an extended period of time.

Comment: But the amperage vs distance comes down to a voltage drop question, doesn't it?  I know voltage drop equates to heat & temperature rise (knowing the current or the resistance), but that heat is dissipated along the 100 ft run of the cable.  I don't see why that would affect the size of the breaker.  Someone with a better knowledge of the electrical code should weight in.

Comment: @SteveSh you are correct.   OP can install a 2880W heater on a 30A. breaker (0.8 x 30A x 120V) or a 5760W 240V one.   If the wire is too long the voltage will drop and if it's just a resistive heater the current and power will drop accordingly.  Not a tragedy, just less heat.   If it drops too much, some other things in the greenhouse may or may not work properly.

Comment: #1 Nobody in their right mind would make/sell a 2400W 120V heater. It’d be for 240. #2 Supply voltage is more like 245V instead of 230V now (~122V per leg, not 115V per leg).

Comment: @MonkeyZeus As far as safety goes, no. Wire ampacity is set such that any length of wire will not overheat at the rated load. At extreme lengths when the resistance of the wire becomes significant compared to the actual load, the resistance of the wire will decrease the voltage seen by the load and thus (for resistive loads at least) decrease the current in the circuit. Long-distance wire needs to be upsized for functionality but not for safety.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses.  Yes I was worried about safety.  As best I can tell and measure the run is approximately 200'.  It is currently just coiled at both ends.  If I understand correctly the longer run is not a safety concern it is more of a question of voltage loss.  I was thinking the increased length adds resistance which would increase heat, but that heat is distributed throughout the length so should I not worry about that?   From here I will now hook up the cable to a 30 amp breaker and test the voltage at both ends and I will post the results.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a 10/3 uf cable running to my greenhouse, but I am not sure of the exact distance it runs underground.

Why not? The installer doesn't add bends, curves, and loops in the conduit for fun. It should be a fairly straight shot unless there's a pool in the way or something.

Measuring from the panel directly to the greenhouse and adding 10-20% would be a good starting point.

> I want to add an electric heater and would like to use a 30 amp circuit but my only concern is the distance of the cable.

What size breaker is protecting the existing circuit? If it's less than 30 then I'd heed caution.

> Is there a way I can test the loss over the distance to inform me if the 10g cable is sufficient?

You could measure voltage in the greenhouse and use a calculator to guesstimate length based on voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have /3 you can put in a, like, 4kW heater at 240V, you'll be running at 50% wire capacity and the voltage drop should therefore be acceptable at 300+ feet.    Is the greenhouse more than 100 yards away from your house?

"Acceptable" may be more flexible than you think.  Even if it's farther, and you get a bigger heater, or you run at 120V .... if the heater runs at reduced output because of the voltage drop ... you're still getting all the heat you can, and as long as other things in the greenhouse still work, you're set.  LED lights and most electronics will be happy with 100V. Look at what you have, read the labels.

Also if you're running 5000+W of heat in your greenhouse and running into problems and want even more .... you must have a pretty big greenhouse and maybe you can budget to lay bigger cable!